# How to set the database initializer in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I don't want to create a database when the application is run. In Entity Framework we use

```
Database.SetInitializer<ExamConn>(null);
```

but how to to use the above statement in EF Core?

Comment: EF core doesn't auto-create a database by default.

Comment: It does, however, attempt to verify the schema. I want to disable this in EF Core but cannot find out how to do it.

Comment: @ItsJason did you find anything on that topic? I've been struggling with the same issue.